# Как при клике на элемент в ответе AJAX получить элементы с таким же data-атрибутом (Wordpress, ACF)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, ajax

Уважаемые коллеги, добрый день!
Суть в чем - я пытаюсь получить в ajax запросе при клике на div с определенным data-атрибутом ответ с элементами, которые имеют такой же data-атрибут, и не грузить все остальное. Как это можно сделать?

Вот то, что я пытался сделать. Это основной блок:

```
<div id="block_first">
<?php 
$material_first = get_field( 'materials_general'); //Главный повторитель
 foreach( $material_first as $main_element ): //Цикл получения значений ?>  
                        <div data-subid="<?php echo $main_element['id_material']; //вывод дата-атрибута ?>"  class=""><?php echo $main_element['materials_name']; ?></div>
                            
                      <?php   endforeach; ?>
                       
</div>
<div id="block_second"></div> <?php  //вывод здесь вывожу результаты запроса ?>
```

Вот мой Аякс запрос

```
$('#block_first div').on('click', function (event) { //отследил клик
    var post_id = <?php echo $post->ID; ?>; //получил Айди поста
    $.ajax({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: {
    action: "material_query", //обратился к функции на сервер
    'post_id': post_id,  //передал на сервер Айди поста
     subid : $(this).data('subid') //передал на сервер дата-атрибут элемента, на который кликнул
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#block_second").append(data)  //загрузил ответ сервера  в нужный мне блок
  },
});
    });
```

Запрос обрабатываю в функции в файле functions.php

```
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_material_query', 'material_query');
add_action('wp_ajax_material_query','material_query');

function material_query(){
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
$id_elem = $_GET['subid'];

$material = get_field( 'materials_general', $post_id);

                          foreach( $material as $element ): //Первый цикл получения значени
                              
                                ?><div data-subid="<?php echo $element['id_material']; ?> ">
                                   <?php foreach ( $element['color_materials'] as $subitem ): //Второй цикл, в котором первый передаём имя нашего вложеного повторителя ?>
                                        
                                        <span><a href=""><?php echo $subitem['color_name']; ?></a></span>
                                        
                                    <?php  endforeach;?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-subid="<?php echo $element['id_material']; ?> ">
                                   <?php foreach ( $element['printing_materials'] as $subitem ): //Второй цикл, в котором первый передаём имя нашего вложеного повторителя ?>
                                        
                                        <span><a href=""><?php echo $subitem['printing_name']; ?></a></span>
                                        
                                    <?php  endforeach;?>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                            
                        endforeach; 

die;
}
```

В общем, через foreach прохожу по двум массивам(основному и дополнительному повторителям). Все это отлично выводит в ответе. Но...Как отсеять лишнее? Как сделать так, чтобы в ответе было только то, что относится к элементам, имеющим тот же дата-атрибут, как и тот, по которому кликнули? Помогите, пожалуйста, а то уже столько вариантов перепробовал, сколько гуглил, ничего не работает нормально((((

P.S. Спасибо уважаемому  KAGG Design за ответ. Жаль что не дождался и сделал через костыли...

```
$('#block_first div').on('click', function (event) {
    var post_id = <?php echo $post->ID; ?>;
    var subid = $(this).data('subid');
    $.ajax({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: {
    action: "material_query",
    'post_id': post_id,
     subid : $(this).data('subid'), 
     dataType: 'html'
  },
  success: function(data) {
        $('#block_second').html(
            $('<div />').html(data).find('#' + subid).html()
        );


  },
});
    });
```

Отфильтровал на уровне ответа Ajax, а можно было просто проверку на уровне обработчика сделать(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из пояснений довольно сложно понять, что вам на само деле нужно, но, похоже, вам надо добавить в цикл один `if`:

```
        if ( $id_elem != $element[ 'id_material' ] ) {
            continue;
        }
```

Получится примерно так:

```
function material_query() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $id_elem = $_GET['subid'];

    $material = get_field( 'materials_general', $post_id );

    foreach ( $material as $element ) : // Первый цикл получения значения.
        if ( $id_elem != $element[ 'id_material' ] ) {
            continue;
        }

        ?>
        <div data-subid="<?php echo $element['id_material']; ?> ">
        <?php foreach ( $element['color_materials'] as $subitem ) : // Второй цикл, в котором первый передаём имя нашего вложеного повторителя. ?>
            <span><a href=""><?php echo $subitem['color_name']; ?></a></span>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <div data-subid="<?php echo $element['id_material']; ?> ">
        <?php foreach ( $element['printing_materials'] as $subitem ) : // Второй цикл, в котором первый передаём имя нашего вложеного повторителя. ?>
            <span><a href=""><?php echo $subitem['printing_name']; ?></a></span>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endforeach;

    die;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Вы правильно поняли, именно этого мне и не хватало...Вроде и мелочь - а, видимо, заработался и не догадался. Попробую так. Уже решил эту задачу, костылями, за что стыдно, но, вроде все работает. Как я сделал. В нужных блоках обработчика добавил дата-атрибут с id. В ответе Ajax применил фильтрацию вывода по этому id

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!